# Is it possible to know which thread completed first?

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I have fire 3 threads. Is it possible to know which thread completed first.

Some sample code

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => MyFunc());
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => MyFunc());
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => MyFunc());

   thread1.Start();
   thread2.Start();
   thread3.Start();

   while (thread1.IsAlive || thread2.IsAlive || thread3.IsAlive)
   {
        //I need condition to which thread dead first.
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to switch to `Task` instead of `Thread`? Tasks have classes that make this easy ([`Task.WhenAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Scott, Is it possible in framework 4.0?

Comment: If you need to know which thread finished first, go back to the drawing board. What if two threads finish at the same time? I can't think of a situation when it matters. [What is the purpose of doing this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Sam, yes you could use [`Task.WaitAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672(v=vs.100).aspx) which returns the index of the array of the task that finished first. But that will block whatever thread you are running the command on until one of the tasks you passed in completes.

Comment: Scott, I don't want to wait for remaining task to complete if first completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to set the winning thread:

```
static Thread winner = null;

private static void MyFunc()
{
    Thread.Sleep((int)(new Random().NextDouble() * 1000));
    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref winner, Thread.CurrentThread, null);
}

public static void Main()
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => MyFunc());
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => MyFunc());
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => MyFunc());

    thread1.Name = "thread1";
    thread2.Name = "thread2";
    thread3.Name = "thread3";

    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    thread3.Start();

    thread1.Join();
    thread2.Join();
    thread3.Join();

    Console.WriteLine("The winner is {0}", winner.Name);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/hGeEeK)

**UPDATE:** If you don't want all threads to finish before you check, there is an easier method using `AutoResetEvent`s and `WaitHandle.WaitAny()`:

```
private static void MyFunc(AutoResetEvent ev)
{
    Thread.Sleep((int)(new Random().NextDouble() * 1000));
    ev.Set();
}

public static void Main()
{
    AutoResetEvent[] evs = {new AutoResetEvent(false), new AutoResetEvent(false), new AutoResetEvent(false)};
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => MyFunc(evs[0]));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => MyFunc(evs[1]));
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => MyFunc(evs[2]));

    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    thread3.Start();

    int winner = WaitHandle.WaitAny(evs);

    Console.WriteLine("The winner is thread{0}", winner + 1);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/q1C8Fq)

Comment: What is use of join here? I don't want to wait for remaining thread to complete if one of them completed.

Comment: @Sam you should have written it when you posted the question. Anyway, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

one simple workaround would be that you write the thread name to a list or something when it completes?

Comment: @BenjaminTrent well whatever collection you write to must be thread safe, that thread safe operation will have its own method of choosing how to break a perfect tie to figure out which item is "first" and which item is "second". (thread safety in this case could be a collection that is safe like `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or putting a `lock` around a normal `List<T>`)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Exactly my point, how would the inquirer know which finished "first" or if they finished at the same time? My comment was poorly worded and should have specified why I thought it to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

All threads can have an arbitrary delay after the last instruction of your code is completed. After the last instruction has run the OS still has some work to do. It can take an arbitrarily long time.

For that reason it is never meaningful to find out what thread completed first. [This is the XY-Problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) This question is meaningless. Its answer will not help you accomplish anything. Ask a new question with the real problem.

You probably want to tell which one of multiple side-effects happened first. Even if they completed in order `A, B` the threads they ran on can complete in any order. The thread order tells you nothing.